# Rounding mode from java Math package for .555 not works

Tags: java, math, enums, rounding, bigdecimal

How about my problem is the following, I am using the rounding mode to round and truncate some quantities but none of the enumerations works for the business rule that my client needs, I give as an example the following:

```
new BigDecimal(5.551).setScale(2, RoundingMode.[ENUM]) <-- DEberia regresar 5.55 OK
new BigDecimal(5.554).setScale(2, RoundingMode.[ENUM]) <-- DEberia regresar 5.55 OK
new BigDecimal(5.555).setScale(2, RoundingMode.[ENUM]) <-- DEberia regresar 5.55 It should be 5.56 
new BigDecimal(5.559).setScale(2, RoundingMode.[ENUM]) <-- DEberia regresar 5.56 OK
```

I had used HALF_DOWN which was the closest one but I came across this case in which I have pure fives and so it didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(5.551)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(5.554)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(5.555)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(5.559)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5.55
5.55
5.56
5.56
```

Comment: That's right buddy, thanks a lot, but one more question. Why did you use String.value? what is the difference when I use String.valueOF ??

Comment: there is no difference, you can create a **BigDecimal** with many params. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html